# How to scale background image on canvas according to device size in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

All I have used to get the image as the background on canvas

```
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.help_4, 0, 0, null);
```

And I get a large image. So can anyone pls. provide me a solution to get the Image set according to the Device size. As I'm new to coding a detailed explanation would be appreciated :)

Thank You

Comment: bitmap class has a createScaledBitmap method

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You just need to configure the [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) variable by setting the output width and height (based on the screen size):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
options.outHeight = size.x;
options.outWidth = size.y;
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.help_4, options));
```

Answer (score 0):

Determine the device width and height and scale it:

```
int deviceWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
.getWidth();
int deviceHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
.getHeight();
```

So in complete you can use the following ready-to-use snippet taken from [here](http://androidsnippets.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/how-to-scale-a-bitmap-as-per-device-width-and-height/):

```
public Bitmap scaleToActualAspectRatio(Bitmap bitmap) {
if (bitmap != null) {
boolean flag = true;

int deviceWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
.getWidth();
int deviceHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
.getHeight();

int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();

if (bitmapWidth > deviceWidth) {
flag = false;

// scale According to WIDTH
int scaledWidth = deviceWidth;
int scaledHeight = (scaledWidth * bitmapHeight) / bitmapWidth;

try {
if (scaledHeight > deviceHeight)
  scaledHeight = deviceHeight;
  bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scaledWidth,
  scaledHeight, true);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

if (flag) {
  if (bitmapHeight > deviceHeight) {
    // scale According to HEIGHT
    int scaledHeight = deviceHeight;
    int scaledWidth = (scaledHeight * bitmapWidth) / bitmapHeight;

    try {
      if (scaledWidth > deviceWidth)
       scaledWidth = deviceWidth;
      bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scaledWidth,
      scaledHeight, true);
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  }
 return bitmap;
}
```

So finaly use:

```
 myCanvas.drawBitmap(scaleToActualAspectRatio(myBitmap), X, Y, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The process would look something like this:

1. Get screen size
2. Calculate new image size (keeping aspect ratio)
3. Decode bitmap to new size.

**Get screen size**

To get the exact screen size of a device, use `DisplayMetrics`...

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

The `metrics` variable will now contain the screen dimensions in pixels. You can get the values by using `metrics.widthPixels` and `metrics.heightPixels`.

**Calculate new image size (keeping aspect ratio)**

To calculate new image size, we can use `BitmapFactory.Options` and tell it to scale the image down by a factor of `x`. To calculate that factor (also referred as `inSampleSize`), use the following method...

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

**Decode Bitmap to new size**

```
// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.help_4, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.help_4, options);
```

The `inJustDecodeBounds` option tells the framework to null out the Bitmap to prevent OOM exceptions, since we are only interested in the dimensions, and not the actual image.

This method will ensure that the Bitmap is scaled *efficiently*. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html